# What is the difference between a phrase and a clause?

Tags: terminology, construction

What is the difference between a phrase and a clause? I tried looking this in dictionary but can not identify the difference. It would be great if I could get an example and formula of what makes a phrase and a clause.

Comment: There's no such thing as Santa Phras.

Comment: [A succinct and very easy to understand explanation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89892/clause-vs-phrase-vs-sentence/89894#89894)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer: clauses contain a subject and its verb, while phrases do not.  Note that phrases may contain nouns and verbals, but won't have the noun as the verb's actor.

The long answer: see [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20090322021948/http://writing-program.uchicago.edu/resources/complex-sentences.htm) from the University of Chicago which has several examples.

Comment: This is what I learned at school.  However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_in_English) says, “In ‘Eating this cake is easy,’ ‘eating this cake,’ although traditionally known as a phrase, is referred to as a non-finite clause in modern linguistics.”  Note that “eating this cake” does not contain a subject.  I am not sure if Wikipedia is correct about this or not.

Comment: IN other words a clause may be a sentence while a phrase is not?

Comment: @jpartogi - that's accurate yes.  A clause may or may not be a sentence (depending on if it is a dependent or independent clause), while a phrase can not be.

Comment: Thanks @Dusty. That makes it easier to understand now. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

From: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/sentences-clauses-and-phrases

- **sentence**:

  - group of words that makes complete sense
  - contains a main verb
  - begins with a capital letter
  - usually ends in a punctuation like period `.` or exclamation mark `!`
  - can contain multiple clauses, separated by conjunctions like `and`, punctuation like commas `,` or stuff like `if ... then`, `who`, `that`

  ```
  He is the author     who          has been writing a very good book.
     [clause 1]     [separator]              [clause 2]
  ```
- **clause**:

  - group of words that contains a verb
  - contains phrases
- **phrase**:

  - small group of words that forms a meaningful unit within a clause or another phrase.
  - many types, including:

    - noun phrase: `a very good book`
    - adjective phrase: `very good`
    - verb phrase: `has been writing`