# "Clause" vs. "phrase" vs. "sentence"

Tags: meaning, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a phrase and a clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/what-is-the-difference-between-a-phrase-and-a-clause)

Can you give me an easy description of the differences in meaning between *clause, phrase,* and *sentence*?

Comment: "C" and "P" mnemonic: Clauses are complete (with subject and verb); phrases are partial.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Phrase, clause and sentence are three of the structural units that create meaning. A phrase is a word or words that don’t have much meaning on their own. If I suddenly utter the phrase *My brother*, you’ll wonder why I said it, but if I say *My brother drives*, you’ll feel I’ve said something that has meaning. There’s a completeness about it, because it contains the verb *drives*. That makes it a clause, but it is also a sentence. But I needn’t stop there. I can go on to say something else, almost without drawing breath. I can say *My brother drives, but he doesn’t drive very well.* I’ve added another clause, and together they, too, make a sentence, joined by the little word *but*. It is perhaps helpful to see two or more clauses joined together as a *clause complex*, although *sentence* in general use describes both single and multiple clauses.

Comment: There is a definite progression, but that reads as though "My brother drives" cannot be a sentence because it's a single clause. If we consider the exchange "How are we to get home? None of us can drive a car." "My brother drives," how is the response (or indeed either part of the first quote) not a sentence?

Comment: M-W3UDE: Sentence [N]: "3 : **a grammatically self-contained unit consisting of a word or a syntactically related group of words** that expresses an assertion, a question, a command, a wish, or an exclamation, that in writing usually begins with a capital letter and concludes with appropriate end punctuation, and that in speech is phonetically distinguished by various patterns of stress, pitch, and pauses". A sentence can consist of a single word, e.g., **"Yes.", "No.", "Maybe.", "Tomorrow.", "Dead."**

Comment: @Bill Franke: I think those examples might be regarded as minor sentences, which introduces an added complication.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I know, but I felt something short and simple was required. In fact, an utterance such as 'Go!' can be all five structural units at once: a morpheme, a word, a phrase, a clause and a sentence. Some grammarians seem to avoid the term _sentence_ altogether, preferring alternatives such as _clause complex_.

Comment: For each the statements here, we need to assume 'with exceptions and extensions'. A phrase *can* have enough meaning of its own: if a word can, even a random set of words can have meaning -- it *may* not always, though. And so on.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Yes, **minor sentences**. One problem with linguistics discussions is that linguistics terminology keeps changing. Another is that there's often a difference between the terms professional linguists use & high school English teachers and university composition teachers use. Textbooks are inconsistent, schools of linguistics are inconsistent, & often the professional practitioners don't even agree on the goal of the discipline. I've been accused of advocating an "anything goes" approach to language, but, though not as conservative as A. Leach, I'm no linguistic anarchist.

Comment: ‘ . . . no linguist would ever say such a stupid thing [as “anything goes”] – it goes totally against the principles of linguistics . . .  it is the kind of glib phrase that people who don’t like linguists claim they say.' (David Crystal)

Comment: ‘It is a complete caricature of linguists’ attitudes to usage that they think anything goes and regard everything that occurs as grammatical. They don’t. Quite to the contrary, they insist that there are constitutive correctness conditions for natural languages, conditions that define the difference between right (grammatical) and wrong (ungrammatical) for individual languages.’ (Geoffrey Pullum)

Comment: Pullum is guilty of spouting pure bullsh*t here. Grammaticality is trivial & almost never the problem when native speakers argue about good & bad language. Style & usage are the big offenders. Pullum & Huddleston (_CGEL_) are guilty of rationalizing the ungrammatical (_viz._, "...gave it to John & I") into the "grammatical" because they claim it's some kind of chimeric idiom when all it is is a solecism used by myriad native speakers who know no better. But when a monster wave breaks on your head, you'll likely drown. **"Push-pin is as good as poetry"**: that's their PC linguistic position.

Comment: @BillFranke: A solecism used by myriad native speakers who know no better? _All debts are clear’d betweene you and I_ (The Merchant of Venice, Act 3, scene 2).

Comment: Dialog in a play, not expository prose. Pre-dictionary, pre-grammar books, pre-modern English. Arguing that "Because WS had a character say it in one of his plays makes it good & idiomatic 2012 English" is like arguing that "Because WS spelt _between_ as _betweene_, that spelling is acceptable & standard 2012 English". The argument from history is hopelessly flawed. We can't draw & quarter bad guys now but must limit ourselves to merely waterboarding or lethally overdosing them. **_Gimme that old time religion. It was good for the Hebrew children. It's good enough for me._**

Comment: I'd never criticize WS's English, mind you. He was a great writer and lived 500 years ago. (I have faith that he was who the literary history books say he was). I'd never change a word of it. Why mess with near-perfection? ("Thou canst not say I did it. Never shake thy gory locks at me", "Was the hope drunk Wherein you dress'd yourself? Hath it slept since? And wakes it now, to look so green and pale At what it did so freely?" How can anyone not love those lines?) But who'd publish such sweet stuff today when nobody'd read it unless it'd been writ by the Bard himself?

Comment: @BillFranke: I thought you might say that. There’s a perfectly good answer, but this is not the place to pursue it. The fact remains that the construction with _I_, in H and P’s words, ‘is used by many highly educated people with social prestige in the community’. I didn’t really mean to go down this route, but posted those two quotations merely in support of your rejection of the ‘anything goes’ label.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I'd like to hear the good answer you allude to. We'll have to do it in chat, maybe tomorrow or later. Gotta close the restaurant now. I'm interested. If the answer's persuasive enough, I will change my mind. I'm not a dogmat.

Comment: I can't really go with this answer, because it seems to be saying that *"My brother drives"* is either not a "sentence" at all, or is somehow only "marginally" so. [The bare-minimum sentence in English has only a subject and a verb](http://www.usciences.edu/writing/resources/USP/SENTENCEPATTERNS.pdf) - that's how I look at it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I have edited my answer to cover this point. As always with giving answers here, there’s a fine line between giving too little information, and hence an incomplete picture, and too much, and creating confusion.

Comment: @BillFranke: I've covered the point on my blog: http://realgrammar.posterous.com/between-you-i-and-the-gatepost

Answer (score 6):

I think it's easier to define this in functional terms and not in semantic terms.

- A clause is a verb, together with all its complements, so that the unit is grammatically correct. The verb is always the nucleus of a clause.
- A phrase is any "functional group" of a clause.
- A sentence is one clause, or a group of clauses.

Of course, provided that the expressions have sense.

For example, the verb "to eat" needs a subject; thus, "to eat" isn't a clause, but "I eat" is. A more common clause perhaps is: "I eat pasta". The noun "pasta" works here as a direct object, but this object is optional: "I eat" is a correct clause because "pasta" isn't neccesary to get a grammatically correct one.

"I eat fresh pasta with my girlfriend" has three complements: "I" (subject), "fresh pasta" (direct object) and "with my girlfriend" (an adverbial). Only the subject is obligatory. They are all "phrases", and phrases are categorized by their nucleus: "I" and "fresh pasta" are nominal phrases, and "with my girlfriend" is a prepositional phrase. "Eat" isn't a complement but it is a "functional group", a "verbal phrase", as well as the other complements, whose role is to be the nucleus of the clause.

Any clause is also a sentence. The difference between clause and sentence makes sense when a complement is specified by means of other clause: "I know he likes me". "He likes me" is a clause working as a direct object of the main *sentence*.

To conclude, "He likes me" is a clause and a sentence while "I know he likes me" is a sentence but not a clause.

Answer (score 3):

**It depends on your theory of syntax.**

In most current non-generative theories of syntax, a sentence can be simple (i.e. it consists of one clause), complex (more than one clause, subordination), or compound (more than one clause, coordination).

A phrase cannot be used as a stand-alone utterance, e.g. "reading a book" is a phrase. However, with proper intonation etc., it can become a sentence, ("What are you doing"?) "Reading a book."

The word "go" can be a word (go), a phrase (go), a clause (Go!), and a sentence (Go!). For example, [Alexander Reformatskij](http://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Reformatskij), a famous Soviet linguist, came up with the following Latin example: I! (=go.IMP.SG). This one letter/sound is a phoneme, a morpheme, a word, a phrase, a clause, and a sentence.

I believe that in generative theories of syntax there is no distinction between a sentence and a clause. In fact, the clause/sentence is a phrase itself (TP or CP or FP).